# Webview Out of memory crash + viewpager

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager, chromium

How to fix this crash,

It is crashing only on `Moto G5+ with Android 7 & chrome version 63.0.3239.111`

**crash logs**

```
W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2021>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory

E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2125>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.

E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2125>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.

E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_manager.cc(3408)] [.RenderWorker-0x6df0a000]GL ERROR :GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY : glTexImage2D: 

E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(5409)] Error: 5 for Command kTexImage2D

[ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9881)] 
[GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:50082280]RENDER WARNING: texture 
bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and 
have incompatible texture filtering.
E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9881)] 
[GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:50082280]RENDER WARNING: texture 
bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and 
have incompatible texture filtering.
E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(9881)] 
[GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:50082280]RENDER WARNING: texture 
bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and 
have incompatible texture filtering


W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
W/google-breakpad: 1.0.3
W/google-breakpad: 1
W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4 in tid 9665 
(RenderThread)
 W/         ]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=9499 uid=10390 gid=10390 tid=9665
```

I am using `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to load list of html text.
It contains img tag and rich text.
The app crashes whenever scrolling the pages in after few seconds.

Comment: This is not an out of memory problem

Comment: Hi Henry, in logs i can see OOM "sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory"

Comment: @SheetalSuryan Do you find any solution for this problem?